# Array of Data Type Interface

Tags: java, arrays, interface

In Java, we use Interface to hide the implementations from users. Interface contains only abstract methods and as abstract methods do not have a body we can not create an object without constructor. Something like this

```
public interface ExampleInterface {
}
```

```
public class Example implements ExampleInterface {
    private static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is not possible
        ExampleInterface objI = new ExampleInterface();

        // However this is
        ExampleInterface[] arrI = new ExampleInterface[10];
    }
}
```

My question is why Java allows creating an array of object Interface and where someone might use it? Is is a good coding practice to use it or it is better to create a concrete class that implements the interface and then create an array of that class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that creating an array of interfaces is not the same as creating an *instance* of an interface. By allowing you to create arrays of interfaces, it doesn't imply that you can also create instances of interfaces now.

Let's give `ExampleInterface` a method for the sake of argument:

```
public interface ExampleInterface {
    void foo();
}
```

When you do this:

```
ExampleInterface[] arrI = new ExampleInterface[10];
```

You are just creating an array of ten elements that looks like this:

```
{ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null }
```

Why `null`? Because that is the default value for any reference type.

As you can see, there aren't any instances of `ExampleInterface` magically created by using that line above. To replace those `null`s, you still have to use a class that implements `ExampleInterface` or get an instance from somewhere else:

```
arrI[0] = new ExampleInterfaceImplementer();
// arrI[0] = new ExampleInterface(); // this still doesn't work
```

At the end of the day, we still don't know what the implementation of `foo` looks like for `arrI[0]` or `arrI[1]` or `array[2]`, and so on, so nothing is broken.

> Is it a good coding practice to use it or it is better to create a concrete class that implements the interface and then create an array of that class?

Well, it's not a *bad* practice. Sometimes you cannot always do the latter. What if you want to store instances of both `A` and `B`, which both implement `ExampleInterface`?

Related: [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)